# Is there a way to find a dead or offline iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I lost my iPhone 5C. It appears to be dead or offline on Find My iPhone. I have tried to get it to notify me when found and to play a sound, but it stills says those actions are pending. Is there anything else I can do to find this phone? It contains important photos that I don't want to lose.

Comment: While your iPhone may be lost, your photos may be safe if you have an iPhone backup, either on iCloud or iTunes. Additionally, other services like Google Photos have backup services, provided you had them enabled. If you don't have your photos backed up, you out of luck unless you ever find your missing iPhone. You will certainly want to set up a backup on your next phone.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113154/will-find-my-iphone-lost-mode-be-useful-if-stolen-phone-as-shows-offline for perhaps a canonical answer to how this works technically and socially.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, all of the methods for locating lost/stolen iOS devices depend on the device being on and connected to the Internet in some way. If it is not on and/or not connected to the Internet in some way then you are just as likely to find the Boy Scout knife you lost when you were 8 the same way.

Note I am not being facetious here, just trying to be clear.

If someone finds the phone and decides to charge it up, it may reconnect to a network somewhere and become findable again. I would log on once a day and see if that has happened. That chance of that happening? Well your guess is as good as mine.